# AngularJS, Cartthrob multi_add_to_cart with options = Nothing adding

Tags: cartthrob

I am building a web app for a client. The gist of it is this...

Using Angular JS / Cartthrob / Stash to load all products. AngularJS to filter through. Cartthrob handling the cart side of things.

The resulting HTML all looks OK to me. I think something is not quite right with the multi-add_to_cart tag and the why I have coded it. I have tried a zillion different set ups to get it to work.

Currently, when I submit, I get a refresh, no errors, but nothing is adding to the cart and debug doesn't show anything. I think I am missing a trick with the add to cart tag. Can you see what I have done wrong?

Product loop:

```
{exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form return="" show_errors="yes"}
    <div class="accordion" id="product_list">
        <div class="accordion-group" ng-repeat="prod in products | filter:query ">
            <div class="accordion-heading order_listing">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 image_container">
                        <img ng-src="{{prod.images_url}}" width="100px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <h4>{{prod.series_description | uppercase}}: <small>{{prod.product_sku}}</small></h4>
                        <span ng-show="prod.sort_group !=''" class="label label-info">{{prod.sort_group}}</span>
                        <span ng-show="prod.tool_type !=''" class="label label-warning">{{prod.tool_type}}</span>
                        <span ng-show="prod.material !=''" class="label label-danger">{{prod.material}}</span>
                        <em class="text-muted">{{prod.finish}}</em>
                        <br><br>
                        <p class="text-muted">{{prod.application_details}}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                        <i class="icon-heart icon-2x icon-grey pull-right"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle pull-right btn btn-primary btn-mini" data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="getDetail($index)" data-parent="#product_list" href="#collapse{{prod.entry_id}}">
                            View Details
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse{{prod.entry_id}}" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <div class="panel">
                      <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Pack Details:</strong></div>
                      {{prod.pack_details}}
                    </div>
                    {sn:general:detailloader}
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Series Code</th>
                            <th>Size</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Add to order</th>
                        </tr>

                        <input type="text" name="entry_id[{{prod.entry_id}}]" value="{{prod.entry_id}}" style="width: 40px;" />
                        <input type="text" name="title[{{prod.entry_id}}]" value="{{prod.entry_id}}" style="width: 40px;" />

                        <tr ng-repeat="series_detail in productDetail">
                            <td>{{series_detail.part_no}}</td>
                            <td>{{series_detail.size}}</td>
                            <td>{{series_detail.price2020 | currency:"£"}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-inline">
                                    <input class="form-control input-small" ng-model="qty" ng-init="qty=''" type="text"  name="quantity[{{prod.entry_id}}-{{$index}}]" style="width: 40px;">

                                    <input type="text" value="{{series_detail.part_no}}" name="item_options[{{prod.entry_id}}-{{$index}}][option_value]" style="width: 40px;"/>

                                    <input type="text" name="price[{{prod.entry_id}}-{{$index}}]" value="{{series_detail.price2020 * qty}}" style="width: 60px;" />
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-small">Add</button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {/exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form}
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

Your rendered HTML would be far more useful than your template code in this case, but there are some irregularities here that I see:

```
<input type="text" name="entry_id[{{prod.entry_id}}]" value="{{prod.entry_id}}" style="width: 40px;" />
<input type="text" name="title[{{prod.entry_id}}]" value="{{prod.entry_id}}" style="width: 40px;" />
```

These indicate to me that you're using each product's `entry_id` as the key for your array of items. But later you have:

```
<input class="form-control input-small" ng-model="qty" ng-init="qty=''" type="text"  name="quantity[{{prod.entry_id}}-{{$index}}]" style="width: 40px;">
<input type="text" value="{{series_detail.part_no}}" name="item_options[{{prod.entry_id}}-{{$index}}][option_value]" style="width: 40px;"/>
<input type="text" name="price[{{prod.entry_id}}-{{$index}}]" value="{{series_detail.price2020 * qty}}" style="width: 60px;" />
```

Here you're using `entry_id-$index` as the key, so your `quantity`, `item_options` and `price` will not match your `entry_id` and `title`.

(By the way, I'm pretty sure that `title` is ignored when adding products which are not "on-the-fly", and that `allow_user_price` must be set and if you want to pass a custom `price` for the same.)

Comment: Thanks very much Derek. I actually posted experimental code on here. Sorry. I did have the array correct at one point, but it didn't work. I got some support over at CT Forum - their back!! Really fast response. The issue was with the array. I had a '-' in it which threw it off. EG: 248-1
Should have been
2481 Nailed it. Thanks again Derek.